# Determine value position appending value in list

Tags: python

One file with different elements to extract and include into a list.
When I try to fill the list that will be included in a dictionary, I need to retrieve the specific information and include in the list in a determined position.
Any help in python will be appreciated.

assembly_report_dir example:

```
Assembly name:  Pav631_1.0 
Organism name: Pseudomonas avellanae BPIC 631 (g-proteobacteria) 
Infraspecific name:  strain=BPIC 631 
Taxid:          11547 
BioSample:      SAMN02471966 
BioProject:     PRJNA84293 
Submitter:      University of Toronto Centre for the Analysis of Genome Evolution and Function Date:         2012-10-10 
Assembly type:  n/a 
Release type:   major 
Assembly level: Scaffold 
Genome representation: full 
WGS project:    AKBS01 
Assembly method: CLC
```

Here are the lines that I tried:

```
report_dict = {}
for root, dirs, reports in os.walk(assembly_report_dir):
    for report in reports:
    accession = '_'.join(report.strip().split('/')[-1].replace('_assembly_report.txt', '').split('_')[0:2])

    path = os.path.join(assembly_report_dir, report) # path = the name of the genbank with the complete path to it

    with open(path, 'r') as inputfile:
        lines = inputfile.readlines()
        description = []
        for line in lines:

            if line.startswith('Organism name:  '):
                organism = line.strip().split(':  ')[-1].split(' (', 1)[0]
                species = ' '.join(organism.split(' ')[0:2])
                description.append(species)

            elif line.startswith('Infraspecific name:  strain='):
                strain = line.strip().replace(' ','').split('strain=')[-1]
                description.append(strain)

            elif line.startswith('Assembly name:  '):
                assembly = line.strip().split(':  ')[-1]
                description.(assembly)

          report_dict[accession] = description  

print report_dict
```

The problem is that the last argument incorporated to the list (assembly) is included in the first position of the list instead of the last one.

The output that I have is this:

```
description = ["assembly", "species, "strain"]
```

and I want the list like this:

```
description = ["species", "strain", "assembly"]
```

Comment: Assuming bust always be a 3 element list, why don't you just declare `description = ["","",""]` at the begging and in each `if` just assign to the desired index ... for example `if line.startswith('Organism name:  '): ... descriptio[0] = species`. Otherwise save each information in a variable and add the to the least in what ever order you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very crude and dirty way of doing...since the length of your list is fixed this code will work without issue...

```
 report_dict = {}
for root, dirs, reports in os.walk(assembly_report_dir):
    for report in reports:
    accession = '_'.join(report.strip().split('/')[-1].replace('_assembly_report.txt', '').split('_')[0:2])

    path = os.path.join(assembly_report_dir, report) # path = the name of the genbank with the complete path to it

    with open(path, 'r') as inputfile:
        lines = inputfile.readlines()
        MAX_LENGTH = 3
        description = ['null' for x in range(MAX_LENGTH)]
        for line in lines:

            if line.startswith('Organism name:  '):
                organism = line.strip().split(':  ')[-1].split(' (', 1)[0]
                species = ' '.join(organism.split(' ')[0:2])
                description[0] = str(species)

            elif line.startswith('Infraspecific name:  strain='):
                strain = line.strip().replace(' ','').split('strain=')[-1]
                description[1] = str(strain)

            elif line.startswith('Assembly name:  '):
                assembly = line.strip().split(':  ')[-1]
                description[2] = str(assembly)

          report_dict[accession] = description  

print report_dict
```

Comment: It will not be fixed but for all the values that I can include after I incorporate the position [n]. Thank you. For now, the best response because of the urgency.

Comment: @F.Lira I just edited code to your requirements...change the value from 3 to whatever is the max length..

Comment: After I will include the option to fill this list with information from other files, so it can be a fixed length.

Comment: @F.Lira It's unclear what you are asking..please explain

Comment: Your solution is ok. What I will implement after is the possibility to include more values (append or extend) in the list. Now I will use the empty list that you gave as an example ['null', 'null', 'null'] (for three elements) and if I need more I include more 'null'.

Comment: yes that is one way...the other solution to this problem is to use a dictionary with index as key ...for example in the above case the dictionary is {0: "species" , 1: "strain", 2: "assembly"}....The advantage of this method is you dont need to specify max_length...

Comment: You got the concept. That is it.